# Can't use ngForm with pre-defined values

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular with Ionic 4 application.

Here's my form html

```js
<form #formAuth="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sendCode(formAuth)" method="post">

  <ion-select placeholder="Country" ngModel name="area_code" interface="modal">
    <ion-select-option code="AF" value="+93">Afghanistan</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option code="AL" value="+355" [selected]="true">Albania</ion-select-option>
    .....
    <ion-select-option code="AR" value="+54">Argentina</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option code="ZW" value="+263">Zimbabwe</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>

  <ion-input type="tel" name="number" ngModel value="123456789"></ion-input>

  <ion-button expand="block" type="submit">Send SMS code</ion-button>

</form>
```

So my problem is that pre-defined values are not working. Fields are starting empty.

As you can see I'm trying to select Albania with `[selected]="true"` and set a default number with `value='123456789'` in text field.

If I remove `ngModel` parameter from the inputs, it works but then ngForm stops working.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set value of your model :

```
<ion-select placeholder="Country" [(ngModel)]="area_code"  name="area_code" interface="modal">
```

in your class :

```
area_code: string = "+355" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the form data in the ts code because the value set here is overridden by the ts code while generation of the form values which is blank or "" by default.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest use ngModel with two-way data binding and set the bound variable to your value.

in ...component.ts:

```
this.areaCode = '+355';
```

in ...component.html

```
...
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="areaCode">
...
```